# AdMob banner view background color is black, want white or transparent

Tags: ios, admob

I can't figure out how to change my AdMob banner's background color when the ad doesn't fit. Is this possible?  The code below wouldn't work for me.

```
self.ad.backgroundColor= [UIColor whiteColor];
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is actually achieved through AdMob's dashboard.

1. Go to **[AdMob.com](https://apps.admob.com)**
2. Select **Monetize** on the top toolbar
3. Select **the application** on the left side bar that you want to change the background color for
4. Select the **Ad Unit** of the banner
5. In the **Text ad style** drop down menu select **Customized**
6. Select **Background color** and change it to whichever color you desire
7. Select **Save** and you're all done

It may take a few minutes for changes to appear in your application.

[image]

Comment: I wish it was the case, when showing house ads with an image banner it doesnt work, seems it only works for Text ad styles as the labels says.  Maybe it's cached also but it didnt work currently.

Comment: @MikeFlynn Have you tried setting the `GADBannerView` to its [standard size](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/banner) inside a custom `UIView` that would act as the background? It would make text based ads not fill the entire area but it would solve the problem with image based ads.

Comment: yes I can't find it anymore at least with newest admob website

Comment: They replaced this feature with Native Ads Advanced

Answer (score 4):

You could add your `GADBannerView` to another `UIView` that you set the `backgroundColor` of. This would require using AdMob's [default sizes](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/banner) to make sure that image banners fit properly. The down fall of this is that text based ads will be restricted to this size also instead of filling the entire ad area.

For example:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@import GoogleMobileAds;

#define ADUNIT_ID @"yourAdUnitID"

@interface ViewController () <GADBannerViewDelegate> {
    GADBannerView *admobBanner;
    UIView *backgroundView;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Create our AdMob banner
    admobBanner = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];
    admobBanner.adUnitID = ADUNIT_ID;
    admobBanner.rootViewController = self;
    admobBanner.delegate = self;
    [admobBanner loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];

    // Create a view to put our AdMob banner in
    backgroundView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                                            self.view.frame.size.height - admobBanner.frame.size.height,
                                                            self.view.frame.size.width,
                                                            admobBanner.frame.size.height)];
    // Hide view until we have an ad
    backgroundView.alpha = 0.0;

    // Set to color you require
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    // Add our views
    [self.view addSubview:backgroundView];
    [backgroundView addSubview:admobBanner];

    // Center our AdMob banner in our view
    admobBanner.center = [backgroundView convertPoint:backgroundView.center fromView:backgroundView.superview];
}

-(void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)adView {
    NSLog(@"adViewDidReceiveAd");
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        backgroundView.alpha = 1.0;
    }];
}

-(void)adView:(GADBannerView *)adView didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error {
    NSLog(@"adView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        backgroundView.alpha = 0.0;
    }];
}
```

**iPhone / iPad**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should insert the ad in a container view.

Then, in the delegate that is called when the ad is loaded adjust the container width to be the same size as the ad view

Answer (score -1):

You need to start by figuring out what views compose the ad view. Probably you are changing the view's color, but it has another view on top of it that contains the ad, and total blocks the parent view.

Start by placing a breakpoint in your code (I often place it in `-viewDidAppear:`) and once in there, type this in the debugger to see the subviews of the ad view:

```
po self.ad.subviews
```

My guess is that you'll see one subview that stretches the full length of the main window. It may even be a `UIImageView` that contains the ad image. But you can continue to look at the subviews of the subviews, either in the debugger or by adding code in `-viewDidAppear:`.

This is probably view you want to mess with. In `-viewDidAppear:`, try adding code to color the subview's background instead:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    UIView *adSubview = self.ad.subviews.firstObject;
    adSubview.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

This code should be safe even if the ad or its `subviews` property returns `nil`.

Comment: This is an ad banner class from the AdMob framework library.  Ill see if it does have subviews.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should fill rect of UIView same Admob size.

```
bannerView = GADBannerView(frame: rectBanner)
bannerView.adUnitID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
bannerView.rootViewController = self
```

frame size(rectBanner) should be match with Admob Size.

Comment: I dont know what you are talking about.